# Covert C# ASPX to handlebars template

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Originally I needed to select and move one `li` out of multiple into a separate `div`.  However, now I need to do the exact same thing but on a JS template (using handlebars).

The C# part is:

```
<li class="l-row__item product" data-product-id="<%= product.Id %>" >
```

I tried:

```
<li class="l-row__item product" data-product-id="product.Id" >
<li class="l-row__item product" data-product-id="${Id}" >
```

(The rest worked that last way, so I'm wondering if I have the naming wrong or if its because its in an id?

Example: `<%= product.Name %>` I turned into `${Name}` and it worked.

Comment: what templating langauge are you using? its hard to know if you are doing it right without details about what your tools are

Comment: Oh sorry, I was told its called a JavaScript template so I assumed only HTML, JS and jQuery would work in it. It says: type="text/x-jquery-tmpl". Does that help?

Comment: there are many different templating engines, Mustache, Handlebars, Jquery Templates, Hogan, etc. jQuery itself is a javascript libary, not a different language. If you could please show us the javascript where you are actually rendering the template, so we can see if you are inputing valid data, given your template

Comment: @user3205098: You're probably using [jQuery templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl). Just an FYI, those are deprecated... If possible you might want to look at other options.

Comment: Ah, okay I didn't understand the question. Its handlebars.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, we're aware, we had a laugh about using them but thats what we're going with for right now. Thanks for the warning though.

Comment: Side note: please avoid all sorts of "thank you" and "my life is hard" and "new here" in post on SO. Such text generally don't add much information to your post.

Comment: Alright, was just trying to polite, I will do that from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is handlebars js then in order to assign the id value to the data-product-id attribute, you need to do the following

```
<li class="l-row__item product" data-product-id="{{Id}}" >
```

However, I am not sure what data-product-id is. Is that a custom attribute?
Because, if you want to show product ID as the text in the li, technically your handlebars template should be as follows

```
<li class="l-row__item product">{{Id}}</li>
```

Comment: Darn, the first one doesn't work. I'm not understanding why because that's how I've done the rest. In fact, it breaks the entire script so when I select something nothing pops up. And yes, it is a custom attribute and I don't want to show the ID in text. Thank you for your help, I'll keep trying to figure it out with your answer.

Comment: You should check the capitalization of the I in the Id, if that's how it is in the data file too. Can you post your JSON content if I may see?

Comment: I finally got it. I went and looked at some of our other pages. Its  <li class="l-row__item product" data-product-id="${Id}" > but it wasn't working because the event was bound to the wrong thing. So you were correct, thank you!